# How to resolve a date macro variable in proc step

Tags: sas

```
%macro example     
%let begdate = ’01Nov2004’d;
     %let enddate = ’30Nov2004’d;
    proc sort data=test out=test2;
    where date between &begdate and &enddate;
    by date;
    run;
%mend example;
```

This code gives me the error: `ERROR: Syntax error while parsing WHERE clause.`
However, when I simply replace &begdate and &enddate by corresponding values, it works.

Comment: When I add the `;` to the first line, and change the ` to `'`, it works fine; so you either have one of these issues, or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally run mine like this:

```
%macro example     
%let begdate = 01Nov2004;
     %let enddate = 30Nov2004;
    proc sort data=test out=test2;
    where date between "&begdate"d and "&enddate"d;
    by date;
    run;
%mend example;
```

I simply remove any assumptions of a date format and refer to the macro variable in the code as a string. Hope this helps!!